# How to overwrite and call a function on a Java object in Oracle Nashorn?

Tags: java, javascript, nashorn

I have a Java object, which needs to get initialized by some Java code. This object will then be put into the nashorn engine. Some JavaScript code will be called, which should overwrite a method on this object. Later back in Java the overwritten method should be called.

This code does not work:

First: the method "test" is not overwritten -> calling it returns "3".
Second: calling the original "test" method fails with an exception "getInterface cannot be called on non-script object"

```
public static class O
{
  public int mV = 0;
  public O(int V)
  {
    mV = V;
  }

  public Object test (Object o)
  {
    return mV;
  }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
  ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
  ScriptEngine jsEngine = factory.getEngineByName("nashorn");
  Invocable iv = (Invocable)jsEngine;
  try
  {
    Object o = new O(3);
    jsEngine.put("o", o);

    jsEngine.eval("o.test = function(x) { return mV * x; };");

    Object test = jsEngine.eval("o.test(8);");           // test is 3 here

    o = jsEngine.get("o");
    Object result = iv.invokeMethod(o, "test", 4);       // this line will throw an exception
    System.out.println(result.toString());
  }
  catch (Exception e1)
  {
    e1.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it. I cannot add functions to Java objects. I create a JS object via helper-function "makeJsObject" and keep a reference to the Java object in a property. I can then add a method to the JS object and call this via invokeMethod  from Java.

```
    jsEngine.eval("function makeJsObject(nativeObject) { return {nativeObject:nativeObject}; };");

    O o = new O(3);
    Object q = iv.invokeFunction("makeJsObject", o);
    jsEngine.put("q", q);


    jsEngine.eval("q.test = function(x) { return this.nativeObject.test(this.nativeObject.mV * x); };");


    Object result = iv.invokeMethod(q, "test", 4);
```